# How to update entire Realm with a single JSON

Tags: json, swift, realm

I have a JSON which is an exact export of the entire Realm.  I'd like to import this JSON to replace/update the entire Realm.  How do I batch update the entire Realm from this JSON?

Here is my JSON retrieval:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSON as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            let exercise = Exercise(value: json)
            realm.add(exercise, update: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
final class Exercise: Object {

    dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var notes: String?
    var workoutDiary = List<Workout>()
    dynamic var goal = 0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}

final class Workout: Object {

    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var sets = List<WorkSet>()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `add(:_, update: _)` with `update = true`, you would need at least define the `id` field of `Exercise` as primary key.

If you don't define a primary key for `Workout` as well, your old workouts won't be deleted. You would need to manually query for the `Exercise` in that case and then delete the workouts yourself, before re-creating the `Exercise` object.

Comment: Yeah, good catch.  I stripped that out of my model in the question for brevity, but it's back in there to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a working solution using ObjectMapper and AlamofireObjectMapper.  I don't love this because it feels kinda brute force with the `realm.deleteAll()`, but it seems to work.

Without ObjectMapper, I ran into problems deserializing the JSON with the `NSDate` field in `Workout`.  It seems doable without ObjectMapper, I just couldn't get it to work.

Without realm.deleteAll(), every run of this function would duplicate the nested List objects `List<Workouts>` and `List<WorkSet>`.  Although the `Exercise` objects wouldn't be duplicated on update, but all of the child objects of `Exercise` would be.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseArray { (response: Response<[Exercise], NSError>) in
            switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                let exercises = response.result.value
                if let exercises = exercises {
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.deleteAll()
                        realm.add(exercises)
                    }
                }
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
```